# Using lpass to unlock an ssh key

Tags: expect, ssh-agent

I'm using the Lastpass CLI (lpass) and want to have it give the passphrase for a private key direct to add-ssh on login as part of .bashrc . the net effect is that I login to Lastpass on when I start the terminal window and then the key is ready to use

triggering login is just:

```
lpass login user@example.com
```

Which already works fine and you can print the passphrase of the key using:

```
lpass show --field=Passphrase  1234
```

where 1234 is the item id

My current draft is

```
lpass login user@example.com    

lpass show --field=Passphrase 1234

if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] ; then
  eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add

fi
```

This prints the passphrase to be copied - not ideal - how can I pass this directly?

---

Edit:
I've been looking at using expect - and believe this might work *if* I can call expect from .bachrc and can pass the out put of the below into a response.

```
lpass show --field=Passphrase 1234
```

Is this possible?